# HAProxy, temporarily blacklist IP if downstream sends back an RST?

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

Would it be possible for HAProxy to temporarily block (Say for 30 seconds) an IP that connected, then got rejected by the downstream server (RST instead of FIN)?

This is for just TCP, not HTTP.

Problem is some people are using many proxy servers to forward junk data to my downstream server. The downstream then sends an RST back to the HAProxy. I could limit connection speeds sure, but they have over 20,000 different residential proxies. I could also limit global connection rate, but then the DoS is somewhat effective in preventing clients from connecting.

Comment: FYI if you are experiencing some unexpected traffic, it may help to include that. Like prevent reattempts to ...